# You're waiting for me, what am I?

Tags: riddle

> You're waiting for me
>   To uncover and disclose
>   To come and judge
>   To disappoint or make glad
>   And probably shed
>   Some light

Who/what am I?

Comment: Are "And probably shed" and "Some light" on separate lines to look pretty or are you being sneaky?

Comment: @Brent just for prettiness.

Comment: I down voted, simply because I think this riddle was a little too broad, probably why there are a few answers that fit very nicely (unless you can give a reason why they didn't fit)?

Comment: @Ina Sorry, I'd expect the riddle to be more straightforward, given the nature of this site... (Q & *A* )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are

> The answer

You're waiting for me
To uncover and disclose

> Needless to say, the answer does that

To come and judge

> Separates those who got the riddle from those who didn't

To disappoint or make glad

> If you knew the answer, you feel glad, if you thought it was another one, you get disappointed

And probably shed
Some light

> The answer would shed light on the riddle

Comment: Right guess. :)

Comment: Yay! Now I'm glad XD

Comment: I thought about this but the 'judge' thing threw me off.  Now I'm disappointed :(

Answer (score 5):

You are

> a hint

You're waiting for me

> I'm still waiting for a hint for this riddle

To uncover and disclose

> To disclose more info about it

To come and judge

> to judge my guess for this riddle based on it

To disappoint or make glad

> if it fits my guess I'm glad, otherwise....

And probably shed
Some light

> it could also shed some light on the answer to this riddle.

Comment: Ahaha, but this is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You could just be...

> the OP maybe?

You're waiting for me

> Once you've made a guess

To uncover and disclose
To come and judge
To disappoint or make glad

> To let us know, judge whether or not we've answered correctly

And probably shed
Some light

> Or give a hint if the answer is still not found

Comment: Well, no. I'm not an... Oh, wait, I *am*, but this is not a right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> death? or the day of death?

You're waiting for me

> Everyone alive is waiting for their time to come..

To uncover and disclose

> The afterlife will uncover and disclose truths about one's life

To come and judge

> Judgement Day..

To disappoint or make glad

> Go to Heaven or Hell

And probably shed
Some light

> Will definitely (not probably, hmmm...) prove if there is a God or not

Comment: ehum...I'm not waiting for that :)

Comment: I didn't say you were looking forward to it.... ;-). 'Waiting' is neutral ...I think

Answer (score 1):

> Judge Dread?

You're waiting for me

> We need to wait until 2000AD before he... wait a sec...

To uncover and disclose

> Solving crimes and telling bad guys what they're being charged with!

To come and judge

> All sorts of things!  "You're guilty of being too fat." etc. etc.

To disappoint or make glad

> Bad guy sad, good guy glad

And probably shed some light

> He probably has a torch for when it's dark out?

Answer (score 1):

> Ghost Rider!

You're waiting for me

> To do a cool stunt!

To uncover and disclose

> Instantly knowing who's done what!

To come and judge

> Sometimes "Innocent..." but mostly "GUILTY!"

To disappoint or make glad

> Bad guy sad, good guy glad

And probably shed some light

> He's on fire!